# java.lang.NullPointerException during ANT build process handling Ordered Dependencies

Tags: android, ant, adt

We have an `ANT` build process that builds all of our android projects at once. It is completely based on the build process encouraged by android.

We switched to ADT20 and the build process now fails when we are building a `release`. The android build process fails when trying to handle "Ordered Dependencies" during the `-build-setup`.

We sign our `release` applications with an `ant.properties` file that contains the `key.store`, `key.alias`, `key.store.password` and `key.alias.password`.

It fails with the following error:

```
C:\PATH\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:546: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

That is all it says without the `-debug` flag.

With the `-debug` flag i am getting this:

```
C:\PATH\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:546: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Exit.execute(Exit.java:164)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.TryCatchTask$CatchBlock.execute(TryCatchTask.java:137)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.TryCatchTask.execute(TryCatchTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue i put the properties in a specific order:

`key.store`

`key.alias`

`key.store.password`

`key.alias.password`

And i took out all extra white space at the bottom of the `ant.properties` file.

This was working fine in the older versions of `ADT`. Not sure what changed to make it fail.
But re-ordering the properties and removing the white spaces fixed the problem.

I hope this helps someone else in the future, because i spent 10 hours trying to track
this issue down. It would have helped if there were better error details from `ANT`.

---

I used this little bit of `ANT` code to make sure white space was gone.

```
    <replaceregexp
        file="${dirName}/../ant.properties"
        match="\s*"
        replace=""
        byline="true">
    </replaceregexp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even this question has already been answered. I'm posting my solution to this issue which I already had once.

1. Remove the content of **/gen** and **/bin** directories
2. Rebuild the project

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue with my build procedure. My solution was just to replace the sdk's tools directory with version 19 and it works fine. I will probably revisit it and update to 20 and fix it later.

Comment: Since then i have updated to 19+ but have not tested that particular issue since. Maybe it was resolved. Thanks for the info.